# aggregate data.frame with formula and date variable goes wrong

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, formula

I want to aggregate and count how often in my dataset is a special kind of disease at one date. (I don't use duplicate because I want all rows, not only the duplicated ones)

My original data set looks like:

```
     id        dat   kinds kind
AE00302 2011-11-20    valv    1
AE00302 2011-10-31    vask    2
```

(of course my data.frame is much larger)

I try this:

```
xagg<-aggregate(kind~id+dat+kinds,subx,length)
names(xagg)<-c("id","dat","kinds","kindn")
```

and get:

```
     id        dat kinds kindn
AE00302 2011-10-31  valv     1
AE00302 2011-11-20  vask     1
```

I wonder why R is going wrong by the 'date' resp. the 'kinds'-column.

Has anybody an idea?

Comment: I cannot reproduce (R version 3.2.2).

Comment: Can you add the output of `dput(head(yourdata))` to the question?

Comment: I see: if I reduce my data.frame first, I can't reproduce this error as well.
So I'll try this: 1st -  I reduce my data.frame, 2nd - I aggregate it 3rd - I merge the result ti the original data.frame. May be this works. I'll report it

Comment: Because you are using `length` as aggregation, the output you showed is correct. Try using `sum` and see whether this gives a different result (it should).

Comment: sum sums up. this is not what I want. I want to count how often a special combination in the data.frame occurs. Sum sums up the numeric value, it is not possible with character values.

Comment: Why do you also group by `id`? If you want to count the number of appearances of a given disease (`kinds`) on a given date (`dat`), I can't see the need for that.

Comment: I use id because in the origninal data.frame there are of course more then one different ID, I want to know how many diseases has on a given day one Patient (ID).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why. 
But I found out, aggregate goes wrong, because of columns I don't use for aggregating.

Therefor these steps solve the problem for me:

```
# 1st step: reduce the data.frame to only the needed columns
# 2nd Step: aggregate the reduced data.frame
# 3rd Step: merge aggregated data to reduced dataset
# 4th step: remove duplicated rows from reduced dataset (if they occur)
# 5th step: merge reduced dataset without dublicated data to original dataset
```

Maybe the problem occurs, if there are duplicated datasets in the aggregated data.frame.

Thanks for all your help, questions and attempts to solve my problem!

elchvonoslo